# extern const declaration as pointer causes hard fault in C?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, extern, iar

I am working on an embedded project in IAR with C programming language. I have a const array in a file, and I'd like to access its contents from another file.

declaration in the file:

```
const uint8_t myArr[] ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

extern declaration in another file:

```
extern const uint8_t * myArr;
```

When I try to access it like below, it induces a Hard Fault:

```
uint8_t content = myArr[0];
```

But I can read the content smoothly If I declare the external variable with square bracket syntax like the below:

```
extern const uint8_t myArr[];
```

What's going on here?

Comment: "What's going on here?" You are cheating on your compiler. You promise that you define a pointer variable somewhere but instead it is an array variable. Arrays are not pointers. As a result the compiler will use first bytes of `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` as an address, dereference it and try to read from that address which is not valid, of course.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you add `const` or where the data ends up. The difference is that an array stored the elements of the array. A pointer stored an address to some value. If you tell the compiler that `myArr` would be a pointer, it will read `sizeof(uint8_t*)` bytes from the address of `myArr` and treat it as the address where `myArr[0]` can be found. But the memory contains the array data, not an address. So `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}` will be ill-used as an address which will fail.

Comment: It is similar as if you put a sign "fluffy kitten" on a box but inside is a angry and hungry tiger. Relying on the "fluffy kitten" declaration will hurt when you try to handle the content...

Comment: When sharing variables it is best to declare them as `extern` in a header file, and `#include` that header file in all the files that use the variable, and in the file that defines the variable. Then the compiler will show the errors about incompatible declarations of the same variable. Hint: array types and pointer types are not compatible with each other.